# How to get Nats messages using pySpark (no Scala)

Tags: pyspark

Found two libraries for working with Nats, for Java and Scala(https://github.com/Logimethods/nats-connector-spark-scala, https://github.com/Logimethods/nats-connector-spark). Writing a separate connector on Scala and sending the output to pySpark its wrong. Is there any other way to connect pySpark to Nats?

Spark-submit version 2.3.0.2.6.5.1100-53

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no normal way :( I found only an option using a python connector, sending output to a socket, and there pyspark processes the received data.